# NHibernate performance and one-to-many relationship

Tags: performance, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

Let's say I have following case. There are two tables `Counterparties` and `Events`. One counterparty can have 0, 1 or more related events.

I would like to get counterparties list with lastest event in order to show id DataGrid, so I created:

two entities:

```
public class Counterparty
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual IList<Event> Events { get; set; }

    public Counterparty()
    {
        Events = new List<Event>();
    }
} 

public class Event
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual DateTime EventDate { get; set; }
    public virtual string Description { get; set; }
    public virtual Counterparty Counterparty { get; set; }
}
```

two mappings:

```
public class CounterpartyMap : ClassMap<Counteparty>
{
    public CounterpartyMap()
    {
        Id(x => x.Id);
        Map(x => x.Name);
        HasMany<Event>(x => x.Events);
    }
}

public class EventMap : ClassMap<Event>
{
    public Event()
    {
        Id(x => x.Id);
        Map(x => x.EventDate);
        Map(x => x.Description);
        Reference(x => x.Counterparty);
    }
}
```

helper class for containing `Counterparty` with the lastest `Event`

```
public class LastestCounterpartyEvent
{
    public Counterparty Counterparty { get; set; }
    public ScoringResult ScoringResult  { get; set; }
}
```

and finally methods responsible for creating list of all counteparties with lastest events:

```
    public IList<LastestCounterpartyEvent> All()
    {
        // Added line of code responsible for data loading
        var allCounterparties = DataContext.Session.QueryOver<Counterparty>().List();
        return allCounterparties.Select(Prepare).ToList();
    }

    private LastestCounterpartyEvent Prepare(Counterparty counterparty)
    {
        var lastestCounterpartyEvent = new LastestCounterpartyEvent {Counterparty = counterparty};
        if (counterparty.Events.Count > 0)
            lastestCounterpartyEvent.Event = 
                counterparty.Events.OrderByDescending(x => x.EventDate).First();

        return lastestCounterpartyEvent;
    }
```

The prefromance is unacceptable, for 30 counterparties and 10 events data processing takes 5 seconds.

I suppose that NHiberante executes separate database query for every counterparty when checking lastest events.

The question is: what can I do for performance improvement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely you need to add `.Fetch.Subselect()` to your `HasMany()` mapping. More information on that [here](http://nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#performance-fetching). But that's only a guess, please show your code which loads the data to get better answers.

You also should mark your collection as inverse (`.Inverse()` on `HasMany()`), otherwise you'll get problems inserting new events.

Comment: I've added missing piece of code responsible for data loading: just simple QueryOver call in last block of code. Thanks for explanations and hints!